# Where is main config file in the Oracle Java JVM?

Tags: java

Where is main config file in the Oracle Java JVM?

I need to hardcode some config to the JVM, like config:

```
javax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
http.proxyHos=proxy
http.proxyPort=8080
javax.net.ssl.trustStore=c:/qqq
```

I tried to write it to the management.properties, but it doesn't helped...

Comment: Why do you think that there is such a file, and that you don't have to just add the necessary -D arguments to the command line?

Comment: I can't add it to the command line... I need to write it to the global config.

Comment: You can call System.setProperty before you make calls that need this stuff. And _why_ can't you add to the command line? _There is no such file_ defined by the Java standard or present in a standard Java distro.

Comment: I can't modify nor programm code, not command line arguments. I just need to config it with "global config"

Comment: @ArthurKhusntudinov Could you elaborate on what you're really trying to do ? Are you looking for a way to set thoses parameters for every system applications or are you just looking for a way to pass those to a specific application without modifying it (software package maybe) ?

Comment: @ArthurKhusntudinov Do you need this gobal configuration for one user, which runs different applications or different runs and any application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html) environment variable allows you to set options like system properties globally in your environment. This means they will be picked up by every java command invokation.

Some examples: http://developer-should-know.tumblr.com/post/119751759112/javatooloptions-environment-variable

Comment: If you export this (e.g.: export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all) for the user, which runs all the applications it will be fine. If it is needed for every user, it can be rolled out via user profiles.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperties(properties object);
```

This will set the system properties.

If you want to set a specified property, then use

```
System.setProperty(key, value);//Both key and value should be string.
```

NOTE: This will first check the permission and then set it. If **permission** denied, then **SecurityException** may occur.

I am not sure you are looking for the same or not, but you can modify `deployment.properties` which is under below location in Windows:

**C:\Users\user-name\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment**

Note: Change the user-name with your userName.

Have a look on the below link:

[Deployment Configuration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/jcp/properties.html)

Comment: It is not solution, because I can't modify code if the programm, that I need to run. I need config if through global config